# How to handle different password encryption with Shiro

Tags: security, encryption, shiro

Assuming an account database with users having passwords encrypted differently. E.g. with sha1 with salt, sha1 without salt and plain text.

What would be the best way to handle a login with Apache Shiro?

Should I use multiple Realms for each encryption method or should I better handle different encryptions in single Realm?

The AuthenticationToken is for all encryptions the same. The user will always login via a form   providing username/password.

Answer (score 0):

Far better to use different realm as far as the connection protocol are not the same. If you move to oaut2 in the future you will have another realm. Enjoy shiro.  :)